# Toggle Query Results in Azure Data Studio without using hotkey

Tags: azure-data-studio

I'm aware of the `Win+Shift+R` hotkey that performs the Toggle Query Results action, to hide or show the results pane in the Query Editor of Azure Data Studio.  Is there any way of doing the same thing via the GUI?

The reason I ask is that recently `Win+Shift+R` has been hijacked by an update to the Windows 11 Snipping Tool and there doesn't appear to be any way of disabling either the Snipping Tool or its key binding (I've spent the last couple of hours trying various suggested fixes).  While I could simply change the keybinding in Azure Data Studio it occurred to me that it should be possible to toggle the results pane via the GUI.  However, I haven't found any commands in any of the menus or in the Query Editor itself.  Am I missing something or is it not possible to do via the GUI?

Comment: I don't believe there is a button, no. But there's not one in SSMS either. I changed ADS' hide results pane to `Ctrl`+`R` almost as soon as I installed it though, as it mimics SSMS.

Comment: @ThomA: Did you have any problem with remapping that key combination breaking other functionality? When I went to set that key combination ADS told me it was already used for 4 other functions !

Comment: I don't recall, I changed the setting when it was still called "SQL Operations Studio" (a better name, if you ask me).

Comment: Which key combination did you give for toggling Query results window?  I tried to give key combination of  `Win+Shift+Alt+I`. Shortcut got created and worked well in ADS. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/bZXEq8l.png)

Comment: @Aswin: I ended up using `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T`.  Not too different from the `Ctrl+R` in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to toggle query results in Azure Data Studio via the GUI. The only way to do this is by using the  `Win+Shift+R`  hotkey or by changing the keybinding in Azure Data Studio.

Below are the steps to create a custom keyboard shortcut in Azure Data Studio to toggle query results.

- Open Azure Data Studio and go to the  **File**  menu. Select  **Preferences**  and then  **Keyboard Shortcuts**.

[image]

- In the search bar, type "toggle query results" and select the command. Click on the  `Change Keybinding`  button.

[image]

- Enter the desired keyboard shortcut (e.g., Ctrl+R) and click  `Enter`  key.